# DFP building responsive ADs (sizeMapping)

Tags: ads, google-dfp

Could you help me to explain this?

I'm trying to display the AD on mobile screens only and I use the following sizMapping:

```
var mobileAdhesionSizeMapping = googletag.sizeMapping()
  .addSize([0, 0], [[320,50], [300, 50]])
  .addSize([727, 0], [])
  .build(); 

slotMobileAdhesion = googletag.defineSlot('/11111/hello', [[320,50], [300,50]], 'dfp-slot-adhesion-bottom')
    .defineSizeMapping(mobileAdhesionSizeMapping)
    .addService(googletag.pubads())
    .setTargeting("pos", "mobile-adhesion");
```

It works fine and displays the AD on mobile screens only. BUT when I use DFP console (by attaching `?googfc` into the URL), I see the following warning:

```
Slot size: EmptyFormat: DivService: DFP
Ad unit did not fetch. 
Ad unit did not render. 
Ad fetch count: 0
Iframe type: none
Warnings:
Ad unit failed to fetch.
```

The question: should I really care about this warning and try to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you resize your browser to a mobile specific dimension, which you have defined in mobileAdhesionSizeMapping variable then googfc should display debug results for this adunit.

If it does (I am sure it will), then there is nothing to worry about.